# Tool for helping with deduplication of Perl code?

Tags: perl, refactoring, code-duplication, deduplication

I'm looking for some tool/library that would scan given project tree, and report on code duplicates - i.e. blocks of code that are repeated in various files.

Is there anything like this?

As it is now, I have to view them (files) all, and search for duplicates, but it doesn't strike me as very efficient.

Comment: How much Perl code do you have? (files, total sloc)?

Comment: Not much. < 30 files, total sloc ~3k.

Comment: I'm completing a CloneDR-based duplicated code finder tool (see www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/CloneDR) for Perl. I really like real examples. Can I have your 30 files? If it all works, I'll send you the report and eventually the production tool. (Zip file?)

Comment: @Ira: https://github.com/omniti-labs/omnipitr - that's the code I would like analyzed now.

Comment: Download.... working... may be a few days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A System for Detecting Software Plagiarism](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/moss/) might work; it supports Perl.

And [here's a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aNickj/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Perl).